# Facebook PHP API v5.0 get detailed posts on group

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-group

I try to get every posts in group using

```
$request = $fb->request("GET","/1172154122867702/feed");
```

I can get the posts array from the group using `$response->getDecodedBody();` but it just contain three property which are the message,id,and updated time.

Is it possible to get the name of the user that post the feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Available fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/post

```
$request = $fb->request("GET","/1172154122867702/feed?fields=message,from");
```

It is called "Declarative Fields" and was introduces with v2.4 of the Graph API.